# Is there a way to achieve parallel scrolling of two tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

Let's say, i have two tableview inside a scrollview. After i scrolled up & down tableview1, and then touch and swipe to scroll the scrollview horizontally to tableview2, i want tableview2 to have the same vertical (up & down) position as tableview1. is there any way to achieve that?
thanks

Comment: i can't think of a reason why you would want to have tableViews inside scrollViews.  A table view is a type of scrollView.  This doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: As zPesk said, it doesn't make sense to have a scrollview inside a scrollview.  Also, because of the way scrollviews work, the subview usually just doesn't work well.  The outer view scrolls just fine, but the inner view's scrolling would be sporadic.

Comment: You could theoretically set the UITableView's UIScrollView properties to only allow vertical scroll (which I believe is the default), then have the parent UIScrollView only allow horizontal scroll, and have some code in the parent scroll view make sure you're always viewing all of one table view or the other, never in between. But zPesk and Ed are right - nesting scroll views is usually a dangerous proposition. Consider using a UIPageControl instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put code in the UITableViews' `viewWillDisplay:` methods that grabs the other table view's scroll position (called a "content offset" in scroll view parlance) and calls `setContentOffset:animated:`. This way, whenever either scroll view will appear on the screen, it will automatically scroll to the other view's position.